# how to disable deepvalidate in grails globally?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can we disable deepvalidate on global level in grails3 as in our case on saving one domain object its trying to save all internal domain objects leading to different errors like unique constraint and all.

We are using mongodb

Grails version 3.3.2

Gorm Version 6.1.9.Release

Answer (score 5):

Globally disable cascadeValidate in Grails 3 or 4:

***grails-app/conf/application.groovy***

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    '*'(cascadeValidate: 'none')
    // Alternatively, validate nested changed objects:
    // '*'(cascadeValidate: 'dirty')
}
```

Reference: https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/
Section: 13.3. Cascade constraints validation

Answer (score 2):

In GORM 6.1.10 a [`cascadeValidate` mapping option was added](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/v6.1.10/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/config/Property.groovy#L119). This will allow you to disable cascading validations for associations. By default, `cascadeValidate` is true.

```
class Book {
    Author author

    static mapping = {
        author cascadeValidate: false
    }
}
```

I don't see a way to configure this globally for all domain objects but setting `cascadeValidate: false` for the associations in a domain will mean you don't need to add `deepValidate: true` to all `save()` calls.

Comment: For anyone looking later, for e.g. Grails 4, this has changed to `cascadeValidate:'none'`, i.e., a string not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

As per grails latest [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html), you can set `deepValidate` parameter is `optional` and by default `true`

**This is `true` by default; set it to `false` to disable cascading validation.**

Example:

```
def b = new Book(title: "The Shining")
b.save(flush: true,deepValidate: false)
```

`deepValidate` (optional) - Determines whether associations of the domain instance should also be validated, i.e. whether validation cascades. This is `true` by default - set to `false` to disable cascading validation.

Also you can set `validate:true` to validates a domain class based on its defined Constraints. or to skip set it to `validate:false`.

**Grails does not mentioned `deepValidate` in GORM configuration options.**

You can refer documentation [here](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html), which provided for different options

Comment: Thanks for the response Rahul, but I am not asking for setting it at each save but at global level so I don't have to write it with each save.

Comment: grails:
    gorm:
        deepValidate: false

This is not working while

grails:
    gorm:
        failOnError: true



This is working

Comment: Wait I'll check is there any other options available

Comment: any success Rahul