# Grails 4: How to Disable Deep Validation of Domain Objects for Testing

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

I'm migrating a Grails 2.4.4. application; and some of my Service methods, which perform domain object validation, are failing their test because the validation is cascading to associations. For example,

### Test Method

```
class AdditionalPhotoServiceSpec extends HibernateSpec implements ServiceUnitTest<AdditionalPhotoService>, DataTest {

    Person person
    AdditionalPhotoType additionalPhotoType

    S3Service mockS3Service

    def setup() {
        [Person, AdditionalPhotoType, AdditionalPhoto, Organization].each { mockDomain(it) }
        person = new Person().save(validate: false)
        additionalPhotoType = new AdditionalPhotoType().save(validate: false)

        mockS3Service = Mock()
        service.s3Service = mockS3Service
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    def "create additional photo"() {
        when:
        assert person.organization.id
        AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto = service.create(new AdditionalPhoto(person: person, additionalPhotoType: additionalPhotoType, bytes: [1, 2, 3]))

        then:
        additionalPhoto?.id

        and:
        1 * mockS3Service.storePhoto(testAdditionalPhoto())
    }
```

This is trying to create an `AdditionalPhoto` with two associated objects that have been saved with `validate: false`.

### Service Method Under Test

```
class AdditionalPhotoService {

    S3Service s3Service

    boolean enableDeleteAllForDownloadedPhotos = false

    AdditionalPhoto create(AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto) {
        additionalPhoto.validate()
        if (additionalPhoto.hasErrors())
            throw new InvalidResourceException(additionalPhoto.errors)

        deletePriorAdditionalPhotos(additionalPhoto)

        additionalPhoto.save()
        additionalPhoto.externalURL = s3Service.storePhoto(additionalPhoto)
        return additionalPhoto
    }
}
```

### Problem

The test fails because `additionalPhoto.validate()` in the service method is validating the associated objects, `Person` and `AdditionalPhotoType`, rather than just the `AdditionalPhoto`.  For production, I like that behavior, but I don't want deep validation for testing because it would require me to create all the domain objects associated with both `Person` and `AdditionalPhotoType` and their associations, and their associations, etc.  It seems like it would create verbose, fragile test code.

### Question

How can I disable deep validation for a domain object just for testing without changing the production code?

---

### Things I've already looked at

- [how to disable deepvalidate in grails globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49528379/715608)
- [How to make cascade to false for all grails domains at global level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49555610/715608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out those both those questions had almost what I needed.

I created the following `application.groovy` file.

#### grails-app/conf/application.groovy

```
environments {
    test {
        grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
            '*' cascade:'none'
        }
    }
}
```